# Azure ServiceBus retry properties

Tags: java, azure, properties, azureservicebus

I tried to find the answer, even in the Azure documentation but it's not clear.

When I set the base-delay property, is the value in seconds or milliseconds ? It's a Duration in code.

```
  cloud:
    azure:
      servicebus:
        entity-type: queue
        connection-string: XXXXXXXXX
        retry:
          exponential:
            base-delay: 2000
```

Thank you all for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is millisecond. You can find that in the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific all values are milliseconds